# Suspend does not resume on Ubuntu 18.04 HP Elitebook 850 G6

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, hp

I'm having some issues with suspend on my laptop. It has worked before but now all of a sudden I'm unable to resume.

**Problem description**

I suspend my laptop by closing the lid. When I open the lid to resume, the screen is just black. The power key is lit. When I press any key, the whole keyboard is lit up but the screen remains black.

**What I've tried**

I've tried several things I found on different forums.

- Editing the grub file and adding nouveau.modeset=0
- Blacklisting amdgpu

and much more

**Computer spec**

Model: HP EliteBook 850 G6

Graphics: Intel® UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Kernel version: 5.3.0-45-generic

**Discussion**

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060248/blank-screen-after-resume-from-suspend-on-18-04-on-hp-elitebook-850-g5-intel-hd) it's mentioned that downgrading the kernel version might do the trick. However, some other places don't recommend downgrading the kernel version.

A thought: Since the power button is lit when I open the lid, maybe the laptop doesn't enter a proper suspension mode?

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Any ideas how I can troubleshoot and provide you with more information?

Best regards

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue (same model, Ubuntu 18.04, kernel v5.3.0-45) and the closest I got to solving it was downgrading to kernel v4.18.0-15 where the suspend works properly, but now my wifi doesn't work (which is why I upgraded to v5.3. in the first place).
You can try the downgrade, you can always change to the other kernel version you have installed.

Comment: Maybe it's worth a shot. Maybe I'm lucky and can keep my wifi even though I downgrade the kernel. Will try it out! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using HP EliteBook 850 G6 with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS after a normal Ubuntu update. It seems like the generic kernel v5.3.0-45 is not so stable. Furthermore, it also effects the ALSA sound-manager, so only "dummy sound" is seen, resulting in no sound and no wake-up from suspend. I noticed that I had installed an older generic kernel 4.19 TLS on my other HP EliteBook 840 G1 and no issues.

The only thing you could do at the moment until this is fixed in upcoming generic kernels is to either downgrade to an older Kernel, please check at start in GRUB if there is a generic kernel 4.xx in your system which you could use for now or upgrade to newer kernel which is trouble-free. This should be tested. The best tool for this to test is **Ukuu**. Note that there is a free version and a paid version: https://vitux.com/update-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-through-ukuu/

Answer (score 0):

When you switch to console (Ctl-alt-F1) and log in in text mode,
does restarting lightdm help ?

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

This will kill your programs. But **if it works**, there is a work-around to resume without restarting lightdm
I found it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584901/lightdm-sometimes-resumes-with-a-blank-display-after-suspend):
In the VT1 console, you can write this 1-line script:

```
 while true; do DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --auto && break || sleep 1s; done
```

It will start looping. Then you switch to the GUI console (Ctl-Alt-F7), and in 1 second it should become active, w login prompt.